# Blank page with error - TypeError: Object.assign is undefined (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have created a myang project where I have used nodejs V8.0.0 and npm Version 5.0.3 on Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS.

I have installed Angular with the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

When I use `ng serve`, the application works property and i have checked it on a  browser with http://localhost:4200.

Every thing has been installed correctly, but I get the below error:

> Type Error: Object.assign is undefined

I have attached the screen shots. Please check and help me display a hello message on browser.

Type error that I am getting on the console

[image: type error]

When i use `ng serve` web pack with everything installed successfully -

[image]

Output showing a blank page 
[image: blank page]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am very happy to say problem solved.**

Open this file polyfills.ts available in src, you will find that these polyfills for IE11 are commented out:

```
    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    // import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    // import 'core-js/es6/object';
    // import 'core-js/es6/function';
    // import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    // import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    // import 'core-js/es6/number';
    // import 'core-js/es6/math';
    // import 'core-js/es6/string';
    // import 'core-js/es6/date';
    // import 'core-js/es6/array';
    // import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    // import 'core-js/es6/map';
    // import 'core-js/es6/set';
```